# Why are my props empty in my laravel-vue-inertia project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I"m starting a new project and I'm not sure why the props in my vue devtools is empty? Where is the information about the user I'm logged in as? Do I have to set that option up somewhere?

This is my app.js

```
import { InertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import lang from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/es'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/reset.css'
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale'

locale.use(lang);
Vue.use(InertiaApp);
Vue.use(ElementUI);


const app = document.getElementById('app');
app.setAttribute(':class',"{'loaded': loaded}");
new Vue({
    render: h => h(InertiaApp, {
        props: {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: name => import(`@/Pages/${name}`).then(module => module.default),
        },
        data(){
            return{
                loaded:true
            }
        }
    }),
}).$mount(app);
```

This is my webpack.mis.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
                '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
            },
        },
    })
    .babelConfig({
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
    })
    .version();
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Yes, you have to setup data to share inside AppServiceProvider in Providers. Check inertia docs for sharing data

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with authenticated users is to [share](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#sharing-data) logged in user as a prop.

A quick way to do this is to go to your `AppServiceProvider.php` file and add the following to your `register()` method.

```php
Inertia::share('auth.user', function () {
    if (Auth::user()) {
        return [
            'id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'first_name' => Auth::user()->first_name,
            'last_name' => Auth::user()->last_name,
        ];
    }
});
```

Accessing the data is done through the `$page` variable.

```
<template>
    <p>{{ $page.auth.user.first_name }}</p>
</template>
```